# Declare temp table inside UserDefined Function in DB2 AS400

Tags: db2, db2-400, global-temp-tables

How to create user defined function with declare temporary table in AS400?

I can't create a temporary table under parent procedure, because i'm using Parallel Jobs. So i need to create temporary table inside function only helps me.

Did anybody knows the solution, kindly update here friends.

Comment: What needs to be accomplished, for what purpose the temporary table would be created, is unstated. Per no mention, consider that a derived table expression [e.g. NTE or CTE] might be capable to achieve what is needed [but undescribed]; NB: derived tables are true-temporary objects, scoped to the query, rather than merely given the moniker of temporary like the GTT for which an actual permanent database file object is created [with all the overhead of any other persistent object].

Answer (score 1):

example of temporary table :

```
      DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE nametemporarychoice AS ( 
      YOURQUERYHERE
      ) WITH DATA WITH REPLACE NOT LOGGED;
```

you can use your table like this:

```
     select * from qtemp.nametemporarychoice
```

or like this:

```
     select * from session.nametemporarychoice
```