# UDF Returning Different SQL statements

Tags: sql, db2, user-defined-functions

I am trying to return two different SQL statements in an UDF based on a IF condition. So far I haven't been able to do it correctly, the code below does not work. How can I do this?

```
CREATE FUNCTION BELSIZE.TEST (aSTRING VARCHAR(50))
    RETURNS TABLE(
    column1 INTEGER
    , column2 INTEGER   
    , column3 VARCHAR(50)
 )
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
F1: BEGIN ATOMIC

DECLARE v_string VARCHAR(50);
SET v_string = aSTRING;

IF v_string = '123' THEN 

        With v (column1, column2, column3) as (
            VALUES (1, 10231011, 'PRINCIPAL')
            , (1, 10231012, 'ADDITIONAL')
            , (-1, 10231031, 'REDEEM')
        ) select * from v;

END IF;

RETURN
        With v (column1, column2, column3) as (
            VALUES (1, 10231011, 'PRINCIPAL 456')
            , (1, 10231012, 'ADDITIONAL 456')
            , (-1, 10231031, 'REDEEM 456')
        ) select * from v;


END
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need 2 different results based on the input string, your return statements should be on an `IF-ELSE` logic. The way you are handling it is wrong in your query. It always tries to return the one in return block.

I've corrected the query matching your requirement. use the `IF-ELSE` logic from that. It's written in `SQL-SERVER`

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.testFn(@aSTRING  VARCHAR(50))  
RETURNS @rtnTable TABLE(
    column1 INTEGER
    , column2 INTEGER   
    , column3 VARCHAR(50)
 )   
AS   
BEGIN  

    IF @aSTRING = '123'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @rtnTable
        VALUES (1, 10231011, 'PRINCIPAL')
            , (1, 10231012, 'ADDITIONAL')
            , (-1, 10231031, 'REDEEM')
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO @rtnTable
        VALUES (1, 10231011, 'PRINCIPAL 456')
            , (1, 10231012, 'ADDITIONAL 456')
            , (-1, 10231031, 'REDEEM 456')
    END 

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: I had tried to do that but I am unable to do that using Data Studio for DB2. See below.

Comment: I had tried to do that but I am unable to do that using Data Studio for DB2. See below.

`CREATE FUNCTION BELSIZE.TEST (....
 
 IF v_string = '123' THEN 
  
  RETURN
  
   With v...;
  
 ELSE
  RETURN
   With v....;
   
 END IF;
 
END`

I get the following error:
BELSIZE.TEST: 15: Routine "BELSIZE.TEST" with specific name "" must have the RETURN statement as the last SQL statement of the compound body.. SQLCODE=-20148, SQLSTATE=429DB, DRIVER=3.61.65

Comment: I think you should not `RETURN` anything from your `IF-ELSE` block. 
1. Create a temp Table before `IF-ELSE` block. 
2. Use `IF-ELSE` block to insert data into temp Table.
3. Single `RETURN` statement from temp Table after `IF-ELSE` block.

Comment: Can you please give me a sample for the temp table? I haven't created temp table in UDF before. Thanks.

Comment: You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39570859/declare-temp-table-inside-userdefined-function-in-db2-as400?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 0):

You should specify your platform and version of Db2...

However, I don't believe it would make a difference here.

The way Db2 returns rows from a User Defined Table Function (UDTF) or a stored procedure for that matter is by ending with a cursor defined inside the function/procedure left open.

So you need something like so...

```
CREATE FUNCTION BELSIZE.TEST (aSTRING VARCHAR(50))
    RETURNS TABLE(
    column1 INTEGER
    , column2 INTEGER   
    , column3 VARCHAR(50)
 )

begin atomic
declare C1 cursor with return to client for
        With v (column1, column2, column3) as (
            VALUES (1, 10231011, 'PRINCIPAL')
            , (1, 10231012, 'ADDITIONAL')
            , (-1, 10231031, 'REDEEM')
        ) select * from v;

declare C2 cursor with return to client for 
        With v (column1, column2, column3) as (
            VALUES (1, 10231011, 'PRINCIPAL 456')
            , (1, 10231012, 'ADDITIONAL 456')
            , (-1, 10231031, 'REDEEM 456')
        ) select * from v;

IF v_string = '123' THEN 
  open C1;
else
  open C2;
END IF;

RETURN
END
```

Comment: Hi Charles, I tried this but I am getting this error in data studio: <delim semicolon> was expected to form a complete scope.

Answer (score 0):

I would code your UDF something like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION BELSIZE.TEST (aSTRING VARCHAR(50))
    RETURNS TABLE(
      column1 INTEGER
    , column2 INTEGER   
    , column3 VARCHAR(50)
 )
RETURN
    SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM TABLE(
        VALUES (0, 1, 10231011, 'PRINCIPAL')
        ,      (0, 1, 10231012, 'ADDITIONAL')
        ,      (0,-1, 10231031, 'REDEEM')
        ,      (1, 1, 10231011, 'PRINCIPAL 456')
        ,      (1, 1, 10231012, 'ADDITIONAL 456')
        ,      (1,-1, 10231031, 'REDEEM 456')
        ) AS v(i, column1, column2, column3)
    WHERE i = CASE WHEN aSTRING = '123' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```